# Where are SQL 2008 Login passwords stored?

Tags: sql-server, password

I need to know in which file SQL Server 2008 actually stores the passwords.  This is a question being asked by a security auditor.

I know I can get password hashes with `LOGINPROPERTY('bbellomo', 'PasswordHash')`, but that doesn't help me; I need to know how they are stored.

Answer (score 6):

The passwords aren't stored in plaintext.  If the auditor really needs the file in which they're stored, point them at the master.mdf file.  This is, of course, for SQL logins.  For Windows logins, SQL doesn't even know what the password is; Active Directory handles the authentication.

Answer (score 5):

Try to look into `sys.server_principals` user names and passwords are in the `master` database.
But the passwords are not stored in plaintext.

Comment: Give him SELECT * FROM SYSLOGINS if he/she really needs output

Answer (score 5):

The execution plan from 'SELECT password FROM syslogins' shows the
passwords are stored in `sys.sysxlgns` in the master database.

Take a look at:
[System Base Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179503.aspx)

Here are the passwords, in the only 2 formats SQL Server will show them to us:

```
SELECT name, password, LOGINPROPERTY(name, 'PasswordHash' ) hash
FROM syslogins
WHERE password IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY name
```

You can probably convert between the formats easily, but I don’t know how off hand.

Comment: this works only if you have enough rights on the server. According to BOL it requires CONTROL SERVER permission. (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345412(v=sql.120).aspx)